# Generate a json array from SQL server using php

Tags: php, json

So, my problem here is this:
I am trying to follow up a tutorial in order to create an app, but i'm stuck at the part of json array...

So what i need is to create something like this:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",

                }
        },

  ]
}
```

While, with what i've done, i get something like this:

```
[{"ID":"1","SPECIFIKIME":"12,9916,7165,1747,6973","IDPEMA":"119"}][{"ID":"2","SPECIFIKIME":null,"IDPEMA":"110"}]
```

My code is this:

```
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) ) {
$return_arr = array();


    $row_array['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $row_array['SPECIFIKIME'] = $row['SPECIFIKIME'];
    $row_array['IDPEMA'] = $row['IDPEMA'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

echo json_encode($return_arr);


}
```

Could you please help me how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all, you have to move `$return_arr` out of the loop, because you are redefining it every time (same as json_encode), then you have to add subarray contacts to make your code look like that you've presented

here's your code:

```
$return_arr = array();
$return_arr['contacts'] = array();
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) ) {
    $row_array['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $row_array['SPECIFIKIME'] = $row['SPECIFIKIME'];
    $row_array['IDPEMA'] = $row['IDPEMA'];

    array_push($return_arr['contacts'],$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```